Send audio from client on 24.04 running pipewire to server on 22.04 running pulse
I have a machine running 22.04 which I use as a media player. It works fine so I'm in no hurry to upgrade it. It is set up as a pulse audio tcp server, so e.g.
export PULSE_SERVER=tcp:mymachine:4713
play audio.mp3

plays fine. But if I have e.g. google chrome running,
I can only have chrome output sound over the network to the server if I quit chrome and start it from the command line.
The client is running Kubuntu 24.04. How do I configure things so that I can select the server from the desktop GUI?
